# What's the word for the emotion when someone's suspicion that another person made a bad decision is confirmed?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

I'm a native English speaker, but I'm drawing a blank on how to describe this complicated exchange of situational emotions in words. Maybe someone can help. I'll just illustrate the situation with a narrative scene.

> Two doctors examine a patient. "Have you been eating any protein-rich foods lately?" one of them asks.
>
> "No," answers the patient. "No protein at all."
>
> Their suspicion confirmed, the doctors looked at each other, nodding _____ly / nodding with _______.

What emotion am I looking to describe? I can picture the facial expression in my head, where the doctors aren't personally involved in the consequences of what's going on, feel somewhat sad about what the other person is going through, and yet understand that the consequences are justified based on the person's actions, all of which is shared between the two people who both come to this conclusion. In this case, they both know the patient should've been eating more protein so they wouldn't have this affliction, are somewhat apologetic that the patient didn't know this, but have some sympathy in explaining afterward that in order to stay healthy, one must consume protein.

Anyone know what words I'm trying to express?

Comment: Given the number of sentences it took to describe what you'e after, I think you're unlikely to find a single word to encapsulate it.

Comment: nodding **knowingly** could work there. The doctors share the "secret" knowledge of what is wrong.

Comment: "...have some sympathy" Sympathetically?

Comment: From your vignette, the exchange of glances is between doctors, not between doctor(s) and patient. So they wouldn't be showing sympathy when looking at each other. They're thinking, somebody's going to have to tell this dodo to eat some protein. Presumably it's the doctor, not the resident.

Comment: From the last sentence of the long paragraph, I suggest they won't have been nodding in agreement, but shaking their heads in perplexity. "How the heck are we going to explain something he should have been told earlier?"

Comment: The word "unfazed" might kind of work, though it's too general.

Comment: _...nodding in an I-knew-it way._

Comment: I appreciate everyone's points of view, but I think @TimR hit what I was looking for. "A knowing look" is what I think would pass between the doctors.

Comment: Sorry, Austin; TimR c between the doctors and that has almost nothing to do with emotion.

'A knowing look' might result from an emotion like 'gloating' and how are they the same?

Can you look back at the Question itself?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the emotion here is ***resignation***.

> **resignedly** adverb [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/resignedly)
> in a way that calmly accepts something unpleasant or difficult that you cannot change
> *‘The poor are always with us,’ she said resignedly.*

Answer (score 0):

To convey their empathy feeling, the doctors are showing **compassion**.

> Compassion literally means “to suffer together.” Among emotion
> researchers, it is defined as the feeling that arises when you are
> confronted with another’s suffering and feel motivated to relieve that
> suffering.
> [source](https://greatergood.berkeley.edu/topic/compassion/definition)

For a feeling that the situation was inevitable, consider **fatalism**.

> Fatalism is a feeling that you cannot control events or prevent
> unpleasant things from happening.
> [source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fatalism)

Answer (score 0):

- Their suspicion confirmed, the doctors looked at each other, nodding *understandingly*.

> (**SOED**) **understanding**
> **3** Of a person, etc.: displaying sympathetic awareness or tolerance; of a forgiving nature. (Early 20th century)

> (**SOED**)  **sympathetic**
> **3a** Of, characterized by, or expressive of sympathy or mutuality of feeling. (Late 17th century)

This adverb can be explained by the phrase "diplaying an expression that shows that they feel their  awareness to be shared by the other".